# How to add shapes to a WPF Window in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

Just out of curiosity, I wanted to do this and created some shapes like `Rectangle`, etc but I don't know how to add them to be shown on the `Window`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add them to a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), and place the Canvas within your Window.  The [Shapes and Basic Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) tutorial on MSDN demonstrates this well.

Comment: Thanks Reed, do you know the difference between a Canvas and a Grid? I mean is Canvas more freeform than a Grid where everything is laid out in absolute coordinates as opposed to automatic alignment? Currently I use a Grid.

Comment: @Joan: A canvas is intended to use the placement defined on the objects themselves.  A grid, instead, uses attached properties to layout its children.  The only real canvas-related attached property is z ordering.  If you're drawing, you typically draw into a canvas.  A grid is usually used for control layout,e tc.